# When in browser view trigger event jQuery

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to trigger an event in jQuery when the client has an element in their viewport?

So for example lets say I select this element in jQuery:

```
$('#star')
```

Then immediately when that element is visible in the viewport I'd like to run an animation.

Any idea if there is a way to do this as I have checked the documentary at jQuery and I can't find an event that does this.

Thanks

Comment: Give a try to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport/7557433#7557433

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
$(function() {
   if ($("#star").length > 0) {
      //do something 
   }
});
```

.length() can be used to find whether an element exist.

Answer (score 0):

If this selector `$('#star')` return anything then its already in the browser/viewport. In that case you could use:

```
if (document.getElementById('star')) {
    // do something
}
```

or

```
var star = $('#star');
if (star.length) {
    start.trigger('click');
    // or something else you need
}
```

If you want to fire something when the page loads you are better off with:

```
$(function(){
    // do something because the DOM is ready
});
```